# Criteria API join: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute

Tags: java, debugging, join, criteria-api, java-persistence-api

I'm trying to make a simple join operation via jpa criteria api, but I'm getting an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [Companies] against path
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.unknownAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:120)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:229)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractFromImpl.join(AbstractFromImpl.java:411)
>       at com.maven_test.models.jpa.dao.ServicesDAO.findAllWithCompaniesByCriteria(ServicesDAO.java:106)
>       at com.maven_test.models.jpa.ServicesFindByIdByCriteria.test2(ServicesFindByIdByCriteria.java:44)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Method looks like:

```
    public List findAllWithCompaniesByCriteria() {

    EntityManager em = EMgrUtil.createEntityManager();

    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);

    Metamodel m = em.getMetamodel();

    EntityType<Services> Services_ = m.entity(Services.class);
    EntityType<Companies> Companies_ = m.entity(Companies.class);

    /*Root<Services> services = query.from(Services.class);
    Join<Services, Companies> companies = query.join(Companies_);*/

    Root<Services> s = query.from(Services.class);
    Join<Services, Companies> c = s.join("Companies", JoinType.INNER);
    query.multiselect(s.get("avatar"), c.get("name"));

    List<Object[]> list = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();

    return list;

}
```

A name of the table which we have to join is "zaks_companies", an error is same with both of cases.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "zaks_services")
public class Services {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
@Size(min = 0, max = 255)
private String title;

//@Column(name = "descr", length = 65535, columnDefinition = "Text")
//@Column(name = "descr", length = 4294967295, columnDefinition = "Longtext")
@Column(name = "descr", nullable = false, length = 16777215, columnDefinition = "Mediumtext")
private String descr;

@Column(name = "avatar", nullable = false)
private String avatar;

@Column(name = "date_add", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "Datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date date_add;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
private Companies companies;

...getters/setters
...default constructor
```

and Companies model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "zaks_companies")
public class Companies {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "companies")
private Services services;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
@Size(min = 0, max = 255)
private String name;

...getters/setters
...default constructor
```

One of my manuals was here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-f4jvljpgQ on 16:50

Comment: No one knows ?!

Answer (score 0):

That's because names of the persistent attributes are case sensitive. In this case name of the persistent attribute is `companies`:

```
private Companies companies;
```

but query tries to use `Companies`:

```
Join<Services, Companies> c = s.join("Companies", JoinType.INNER);
```

In join one should use `companies` as follows:

```
Join<Services, Companies> c = s.join("companies", JoinType.INNER);
```